# Unable to deserialize complex/dynamic JSON to Java classes using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I've been trying to deserialize a JSON to Java classes using Gson, but the JSON structure is too complex for me to handle. The JSON looks like this (I've trimmed some of it because of repetitions):

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.encounter_channel.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>":{
            "type":"DV_TEXT",
            "name":{
               "en":"Encounter channel"
            },
            "attrs":[
               "value"
            ]
         },
         "openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.monitoring_reason.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>":{
            "type":"DV_TEXT",
            "name":{
               "en":"Monitoring reason"
            },
            "attrs":[
               "value"
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "163eee06-83a4-4fd8-bf65-5d6a3ef35ac5":{
            "d5760d01-84dd-42b2-8001-a69ebaa4c2df":{
               "date":"2020-08-06 09:45:31",
               "cols":[
                  {
                     "type":"DV_TEXT",
                     "path":"openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.encounter_channel.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>",
                     "values":[
                        {
                           "instanceTemplatePath":"prova_de_conceito.en.v1/context/other_context[at0001]/items[archetype_id=openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.encounter_channel.v0](0)/items[at0001](0)/value",
                           "value":"null"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"DV_TEXT",
                     "path":"openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.monitoring_reason.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>",
                     "values":[
                        {
                           "instanceTemplatePath":"prova_de_conceito.en.v1/context/other_context[at0001]/items[archetype_id=openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.monitoring_reason.v0](1)/items[at0001](0)/value",
                           "value":"null"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "fb366b72-d567-4d23-9f5f-356fc09aff6f":{
               "date":"2020-08-06 10:02:26",
               "cols":[
                  {
                     "type":"DV_TEXT",
                     "path":"openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.encounter_channel.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>",
                     "values":[
                        {
                           "instanceTemplatePath":"prova_de_conceito.en.v1/context/other_context[at0001]/items[archetype_id=openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.encounter_channel.v0](0)/items[at0001](0)/value",
                           "value":"Consulta presencial"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"DV_TEXT",
                     "path":"openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.monitoring_reason.v0/items[at0001]/value<DV_TEXT>",
                     "values":[
                        {
                           "instanceTemplatePath":"prova_de_conceito.en.v1/context/other_context[at0001]/items[archetype_id=openEHR-EHR-CLUSTER.monitoring_reason.v0](1)/items[at0001](0)/value",
                           "value":"Consulta"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "pagination":{
      "max":20,
      "offset":0,
      "nextOffset":20,
      "prevOffset":0
   },
   "timing":"475 ms"
}
```

The main JSON object has three fields: `results`, `pagination` and `timing`. I can deserialize the `pagination` and `timing` just fine, as they always have the same structure. I cannot properly deserialize the `results` though.

`results` is always a list of two different objects. The second object, in particular, is the most complex one, as its field names are not static. The UUID name references always change on each API response. For instance, the field named `"163eee06-83a4-4fd8-bf65-5d6a3ef35ac5"` might have another id in the next JSON response. Therefore, I cannot give it a proper field name in the corresponding Java class. The same goes for `"d5760d01-84dd-42b2-8001-a69ebaa4c2df"` and `"fb366b72-d567-4d23-9f5f-356fc09aff6f"` in this case.

Any ideas on how to properly deserialize this kind of JSON using Gson? I've tried a couple of different approaches, but nothing has truly worked so far.

In most recent attempt I tried to use the JsonDeserializer approach in order to differentiate the type of objects in the `results` list. My current implementation looks like this (getters and setters were hidden because of space):

QueryResponse.java

```
public class QueryResponse {
    private List<Map<String, ResultInterface>> results;
    private Pagination pagination;
    private String timing;
}
```

Pagination.java

```
public class Pagination {
    private Integer max;
    private Integer offset;
    private Integer nextOffset;
    private Integer previousOffset;
}
```

ResultInterface.java

```
public interface ResultInterface {

}
```

ElementDefinition.java

```
public class ElementDefinition implements ResultInterface {
    private String type;
    private Name name;
    private List<String> attrs;
}
```

Name.java

```
public class Name {
    private String en;
    private String es;
}
```

Compositions.java

```
public class Compositions implements ResultInterface {
    private Map<String, Composition> compositions;
}
```

Composition.java

```
public class Composition {
    private String date;
    private List<Col> cols;
}
```

Col.java

```
public class Col {
    private String type;
    private String path;
    private List<Value> values;
}
```

Value.java

```
public class Value {
    private String instanceTemplatePath;
    private String value;
    private String magnitude;
    private String units;
    private String code;
    private String terminology_id;
}
```

ResultInterfaceDeserializer.java

```
public class ResultInterfaceDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ResultInterface> {
    
    @Override
    public ResultInterface deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) json;
        JsonElement typeObj = jObject.get("type");

        if (typeObj != null) {
            return context.deserialize(json, ElementDefinition.class);
        } else {
            return context.deserialize(json, Compositions.class);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling Gson like this:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        
builder.registerTypeAdapter(ResultInterface.class, new ResultInterfaceDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
        
QueryResponse queryResponse = gson.fromJson(externalJsonResponse, QueryResponse.class);
```

The problem with this implementation is that there is nothing named `compositions` in the JSON structure, thus the `Compositions.java` class is not correctly identified. I know I have to use Java structures like `Map<String, SomeObject>`, but the problem is that there are too many dynamically named Json fields here, and I cannot "grab" them if they have no fixed name identifier.

UPDATE

I managed to find a solution. I'd say it's actually a workaround and probably not the most clean or elegant solution.
The problem with my current implementation was that I was trying to "grab" a JSON field called `compositions` when in fact it didn't exist. So, I decided to manipulate the JSON and add that field myself (in the code).
I changed the deserializer class to:

```
public class ResultInterfaceDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ResultInterface> { 
    public String encloseJsonWithCompositionsField(JsonElement json) {
        return "{\"compositions\":" + json.toString() + "}";
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResultInterface deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) json;
        
        if (jObject.get("type") != null) {
            return context.deserialize(json, ElementDefinition.class);
        } else {
            JsonElement jsonWithCompositionsField = new JsonParser().parse(encloseJsonWithCompositionsField(json));
            return context.deserialize(jsonWithCompositionsField, Compositions.class);
        }
    }
}
```

With this change, I can now "grab" the compositions field and get the data in Java POJOs.

Comment: `Map<String, Result>`?

Comment: Could you be more specific? There's no `Result` class defined.

Comment: Are you able to get the JsonSchema for this JSON from the API provider? this will help you a lot to be able to map this JSON, then you can use this great site to convert it probably (it may help also with this JSON but you will get stuck with this dynamically named attributes) 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Also, you can mapped as a plain object and do all the work manually (iterate and get each attribute name and values and so on... )

Comment: No, I have no JsonSchema to work with. I can't really use that website to automatically generate classes because of the dynamically named fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this by registering an additional JsonDeserializer for `Compositions`:

```java
public class CompositionsDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Compositions> {
    public static final CompositionsDeserializer INSTANCE = new CompositionsDeserializer();
    
    private CompositionsDeserializer() { }
    
    @Override
    public Compositions deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Compositions compositions = new Compositions();
        Map<String, Composition> compositionsMap = new HashMap<>();
        compositions.compositions = compositionsMap;
        
        JsonObject compositionsJson = json.getAsJsonObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> compositionEntry : compositionsJson.entrySet()) {
            Composition composition = context.deserialize(compositionEntry.getValue(), Composition.class);
            compositionsMap.put(compositionEntry.getKey(), composition);
        }
        
        return compositions;
    }
}
```

And then register that deserializer on the GsonBuilder as well:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(ResultInterface.class, new ResultInterfaceDeserializer())
    .registerTypeAdapter(Compositions.class, CompositionsDeserializer.INSTANCE)
    .create();
```